# What is the difference in doctrine between the Pentecostal church and the Assemblies of God church?

Tags: denomination-survey, belief, pentecostalism

I attend an AG church and am told the AG churches are Pentecostal, but a distinction is drawn between AG and Pentecostal. What's the doctrinal difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a difference, in the way you have phrased your question.

Rather, the difference is that Pentecostalism includes many denominations, *one of which* is the Assemblies of God church.

You can read more about [Pentecostalism on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentecostalism), as well as [Assemblies of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assemblies_of_God).  Of particular note, the second article says (emphasis added):

> The Assemblies of God (AG), is a group of over 140 autonomous but loosely associated national groupings of churches which together form **the world's largest Pentecostal denomination**.

Comment: So what you're saying is, is that there is no doctrinal difference between the Pentecostal and AG church?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you've made a category error. AG is Pentecostal, in the same way that poodles are dogs. Not all Pentecostals are AG, in the same way that not all dogs are poodles. Your question is like asking "What is the difference between a dog and a poodle?"

Comment: I see, I was under the impression that there was a difference between the two.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference, as I have explained. But not the difference your question assumes.